# Visibility of the opening workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem with my program. Well i am trying to open Another workbook and copy some of the data from specific range of cells. Well I don't want to for the other work to flicker while it's opening and closing.  For some reason there is an error 9. For sure i am starting with macros for the Office Excell so I know it isn't perfect.

I tried some guieds but it was not working. Well my expectation is: Open the Other workbook with data, Copy it into my workbook and the close the otherwork book with data, everything should be invisble like It's nothing happening. To be honest the flickering work book is not looking good.

```
Sub GetSheet1()
Dim appExcel As Application

Path = "'Path'"
filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

Do While filename <> ""
Set appExcel = New Application
appExcel.Visible = False
appExcel.Workbooks.Open filename:=Path & filename, ReadOnly:=True
Workbooks(filename).Worksheets(1).Range("A1:F20").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B2")
Workbooks(filename).Close
appExcel.Quit
filename = Dir()
Loop

End Sub`
```

Comment: You can try adding `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` at the top and `Application.ScreenUpdating=True` at the bottom. This introduces new problems - you should have error handling so if there are errors you aren't left with screen updating on. Also if this takes a long time your application can look frozen. For beginners (if that is what you are - might be best to live with the flickering while you continue to develop your base set of skills with VBA. Note: not adding as a answer because this has been explained ten thousand times before.

Comment: Okey, this looks cool. Didn't think about it that way. Well I am still in developing of this program, so adding some error handling isn't a bad idea. Thank you for now.